# utilização do localdb com o team foundation server

Tags: c++, sql-server, team-foundation-server

Tenho uma solução em visual studio, que contém vários projectos C++ e com um projecto SQL DB, que é publicado numa instância do localdb. O controlo de versões é feito utilizado o Team Foundation Server.

**A minha dúvida é a seguinte:** como posso configurar o projecto sql na solução para que, além de alterar e partilhar com a equipa o esquema da BD, possa também partilhar os dados que formos inserindo?

Answer (score 1):

Crie um projeto específico para o banco de dados, na versão 2010 ou mais recente do Visual Studio possui templates de projetos Database SQL Server, onde é possível mantê-lo atravéz do team fundation server.
Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Sim, obrigado! Eu já fiz isso. Só que no projecto de BD são guardados apenas os ficheiros SQL com o esquema. Para o TFS vai apenas o esquema de tabelas, relações etc... os dados ficam associados a cada instância